# More than 3 times until something will not be

Tags: probability

i have an exercise:

In a company that sells electric power,the employees calls random phone numbers so that will promote to gain more customers.We already know that the company has 20% of the market.What is the possibility one employee who work there and calls phone numbers ,will do, **more than** 3 calls, until **will get someone who is not** already a customer of this company?
What i did was `100% - 20% = 80%.`Then i thought `(80^3 )%  = 512000%=512.` 
Am i right?

Comment: Probability must be between $0$ and $1$.  You want $.8^3=.512=51.2\%$

Comment: so the answer is 51.2? @saulspatz

Comment: The answer is $.512$.  If you want to express it as a percentage, it is $51.2\%$

Comment: (80^3%) is wrong? i should have wrote it 8^3?

Comment: Aren't you reading what I write?  It is $.8^3$.  That is $0.8^3$.  This is different from $8^3$.

Comment: @saulspatz man i got it <3 thank you a lot :) sorry i am reading it but i am delaying little bit

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct.

The answer should be $(0.2)^3=0.008$.

This is because you have to call a member of the company three times, and then you *might* call someone who isn't a member of the company.

Comment: i am not sure about it